# Contents of a RadzenGrid Column right justified and Title centered

Tags: css, blazor, radzen

I would like the contents of my column to be right justified and the title centered.

I tried this:

```
<RadzenDataGridColumn Property="BestD_Waarde"
                   TItem="WebOrderModelDetail"       
                   TextAlign="Radzen.TextAlign.Right"
                   FormatString="{0:N2}"
                   Width="60px">
                   <HeaderTemplate>
                       <div style="text-align: center !important;">Totaal</div>
                   </HeaderTemplate>
```

But the title remains right justified.

Comment: Radzen suggests to use 
<span class="rz-column-title-content">
      <div style="text-align: center !important;">Totaal</div>
  </span>
That did not work for me.   So I decided to just add 2 &nbsp's to the title of the numeric columns.   Not the most elegant solution, but it does do what I need.